# Как сделать сайтбар на на всю высоту экрана, при наличии такого субменю?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Вот полный код:
https://jsfiddle.net/kvofd9eb/2/

```
        .aside {
      background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
              box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      max-width: 280px;
      padding: 20px;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .aside__item {
      margin: 0 0 45px 0;
    }

    .aside__item ul li {
      margin: 0 0 25px 0;
      position: relative;
    }

    .aside__item ul li:last-child {
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }

    .aside__item ul li a {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
    }

    .aside__item ul li a span {
      margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }

    .aside__item ul li .sub-menu {
      background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
              box-shadow: 2px 0 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      display: block;
      max-width: 200px;
      min-width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      right: -260px;
      top: -10px;
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

    .aside__item .dashboard-arrow {
      margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    }

    .logo {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    }

    .logo__img {
      margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    }

    .logo__img img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .logo__title {
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #7e72f2;
    }

    .logo__circle {
      margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    }

    .dashboard {
      margin: 0 0 40px 0;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .dashboard ul li {
      margin: 0 0 6px 0;
    }

    .dashboard ul li:last-child {
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }

    .dashboard ul li a {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
    }

    .dashboard__home span {
      margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }

    .dashboard__home .dashboard-arrow {
      margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    }

    .dashboard__analytics span {
      margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }

    .dashboard__ecommerce span {
      margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }

    .app__title,
    .ul__title,
    .form__title,
    .pages__title,
    .charts-maps__title,
    .extensions__title,
    .others__title {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

    .btn {
      padding: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
    }

    .btn--gray {
      color: #2c2c2c;
      background-color: #ececec;
      -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 8px rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.6);
              box-shadow: -1px 1px 8px rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.6);
    }

    .btn--violet {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #9e94ff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 8px rgba(158, 148, 255, 0.6);
              box-shadow: -1px 1px 8px rgba(158, 148, 255, 0.6);
    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1;
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
      background-color: #F2F2F2;
    }

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    a {
      color: inherit;
    }

    a,
    a:visited,
    a:hover,
    a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul,
    li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    button {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    img {
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

1. Я сымитировал ситуацию, когда открыты субменю, и конкретно в последнем таком субменю есть 4 пункта, из-за этого высота документа получилась выше, чем 100vh заданный самому сайтбару. Таким образом получается что сайтбар растянулся не на всю высоту и имеется зазор. Как можно исправить ситуацию средствами css?
   [image: демонстрация проблемы]
2. Приемлемо ли вообще таким образом верстать субменю и в принципе, как бы вы оценили верстку и есть ли более лучшие варианты для данной реализации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел код, и решил эту задачу тем что у каждого списка есть возможность создать псевдо элемент, который можно подставить таким образом что получиться удлинить колонку, думаю решение вам понравиться, вот код: https://jsfiddle.net/bgwt4cfe/

```
.aside {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    max-width: 280px;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    &__item{
        margin: 0 0 45px 0;
        ul {
            li {
                margin: 0 0 25px 0;
                position: relative;
                &:last-child {
                    margin: 0 0 0 0;
                }
                a {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    position: relative;
                    z-index:2;
                    span {
                        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
                    }
                }
                .sub-menu {
                    background-color: #fff;
                    box-shadow: 2px 0 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
                    display: block;
                    max-width: 200px;
                    min-width: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: -260px;
                    top: -10px;
                    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                    
                    &::after{
                      content:'';
                      position: absolute;
                      left:-280px;
                      top:0;
                      background-color: #fff;
                      width: 280px;
                      height: 100%;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .dashboard-arrow {
            margin: 0 0 0 auto;
        }
    }
}
.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    &__img {
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
        img {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    &__title {
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #7e72f2;
    }
    &__circle {
        margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    }
}
.dashboard {
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    ul {
        li {
            margin: 0 0 6px 0;
            &:last-child {
                margin: 0 0 0 0;
            }
            a {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
        }
    }
    &__home {
        span {
            margin: 0 0 0 10px;
        }
        .dashboard-arrow {
            margin: 0 0 0 auto;
        }
    }
    &__analytics {
        span {
            margin: 0 0 0 10px;
        }
    }
    &__ecommerce {
        span {
            margin: 0 0 0 10px;
        }
    }
}

.app,
.ul,
.form,
.pages,
.charts-maps,
.extensions,
.others {
    &__title {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }
}

.btn {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
}
.btn--gray {
    color: #2c2c2c;
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 8px rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.6);
}
.btn--violet {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: rgb(158, 148, 255);
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 8px rgba(158, 148, 255, 0.6);
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
    color: inherit;
}
a,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul,
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Оу, это гениально! Большое вам спасибо